# Developer Console security

Tags: security, developer-console

**Context:** We have multiple Business Admins in different countries, who can only see records from their market in Salesforce. Now, we're considering giving these Business Admins access to the Developer Console by checking the *API Enabled* checkbox on their profile.

**Question:** Does enabling the Developer Console (by checking *API Enabled*) mean users can write Apex/queries that affects records they normally can't see in Salesforce?

**Update:** Just for future reference: It turned out that if you're a System Administrator and you login as another user, you still see the Developer Console in the menu. If you login as another user directly though, it's not there and Bradley's answer is where you should look for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling the Developer Console requires more than just "API Enabled".  See [Using the Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_system_log.htm) for all the permissions required.

One of them is "View All Data" so yes, it would give users access to view all data in the system. It doesn't require "Modify All Data" so there shouldn't be any issue with editing data they normally wouldn't be able to edit.

Comment: Do you mean the "View All" checkbox under "Data Administration" on the profile? And if so, would checking this checkbox for only one object/custom object be enough to show the Developer Console?

Comment: No, there is a permission under "System Permissions" called "View All Data".  Enabling for a single object will not enable the developer console.

Comment: Thanks for your response! :-) I've also added an update to my question, explaining my confusion in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bradley. It will take more than enabling API. When you say Business Admins in different countries cannot see data or only the data in their market wouldn't be easier to look at their roles ? It might be that you have some sharing rules which restrict that kind of access.